# Yodlee CoreExceptionFaultMessage

Tags: yodlee

On a 30 trial from Yodlee and after compiling and running sampleapp (soap)

I have setup the property file with my credential and using the console tool: 
./yconsole.sh

when trying to login or register a user, i get a message followed by exception:

```
    CobrandContext has expired (23214334 minutes old), creating new one...

    {http://core.soap.yodlee.com}CoreExceptionFault:   <faultText>com.yodlee.util.system.ycache.CobrandNotSupportedException: The cache CobrandCache10007152 is not initialized. </faultText>
```

CoreExceptionFaultMessage

if you are familiar with the platform, do you think this bug is in the app or on the server side ,  any work around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes when you are not using the right Cobrand with the right SOAP server. So you will have to change either the SOAP URL or the cobrand credentials.

Comment: I have started from scratch and now I am getting.InsufficientPrivilegeException: Accessibility denied. My 30 trial started yesterday. and when trying to login one of the five users, I get bad credential.

Comment: The developer environment doesn't allow you to register as you are already provided with 5 registered user. Login in the any of the 5 user should not be problem, just cross verify if you are copying the username and password correctly.  If you are using the java sample apps from yodlee then check the readStr() method in IOUtils class and comment the line where the code is trimming the String if it finds "#" character.

Comment: Thanks buddy, would you please the other question I just posted on yodlee.